# Use a for-loop that writes a data set based on different inputs for an RxODE model

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to simulate data for different inputs of pharmacokinetic parameters that are unique for a drug (monoclonal antibodies). Normally, I would generate simulated date one by one, but I want to do it faster. For now, I will give you two examples of drugs and their corresponding pharmacokinetic parameters:

```
Drug <- c("drug 1", "drug 2")
CL <- c(0.0005, 0.0007)
Vd <- c(0.1, 0.09)
Q <- c(0.0003, 0.0035)
Vp <- c(0.1, 0.08)

df <- data.frame(Drug, CL, Vd, Q, Vp)
```

This is the RxODE model that I've written. There where there is an 'x', there should be either a value or a name.

```
#Parameters 
mod_CL <- x    #x for value          
mod_V1 <- x    #x for value           
mod_Q <- x     #x for value           
mod_Vp <- x    #x for value  
a <- 0.89
b <- 0.98
g <- 0.67
d <- 0.95
amt <- 10
BWsub <- 3 
IIV_CL <- 0
IIV_V1 <- 0
ETA_CL <- IIV_CL
ETA_V1 <- IIV_V1

#Model structure
MOD_PKPD <- RxODE("
                  #PK Parameters
                  TVCL = theta1;      
                  TVV1 = theta2;      
                  TVQ = theta3;         
                  TVVP = theta4;
                  
                  
                  #Individual PK values
                  CL = theta1*((BWS)^alfa)*exp(eta_CL);
                  V1 = theta2*((BWS)^beta)*exp(eta_V1);
                  Q = theta3*((BWS)^gamma);
                  Vp = theta4*((BWS)^delta);
                  
                  #Rate of transfer
                  K10 = CL/V1;
                  K12 = Q/V1;
                  K21 = Q/Vp;
                  
                  #Differentials
                  d/dt(centr) = -K10*centr - K12*centr + K21*periph;
                  d/dt(periph) = K12*centr - K21*periph;
                  
                  #Drug exposure
                  C1 = centr/V1;
                  C2 = periph/Vp;
                  d/dt(AUC1) = C1;
                  d/dt(AUC2) = C2;
                  
                  #Error model
                  obs = C1*(1 + prop_err) ; #Proportional error model
                  ")

#Thetas, omegas, sigmas and inits
paras <- c(theta1 = mod_CL, 
           theta2 = mod_V1, 
           theta3 = mod_Q, 
           theta4 = mod_Vp,
           BWS = BWsub,
           alfa = a, beta = b, 
           gamma = g, delta = d)

omega_rtv           <-  diag(2);      
diag(omega_rtv)     <-  matrix(c(ETA_CL,ETA_V1))  
dimnames(omega_rtv) <- list(NULL, c("eta_CL",
                                    "eta_V1"))
sigma_rtv       <- diag(1);
diag(sigma_rtv) <- c(0.01^2)
dimnames(sigma_rtv) <- list(NULL, c("prop_err"))

inits <- c(centr = 0, periph = 0)

#Dosing
ev1 <- eventTable() %>% 
  add.dosing(dose = amt*BWsub, 
             nbr.doses = 1, dur = 0.5) %>% 
  add.sampling(seq(0, 504, by = 0.1))


#Simulation
x <- solve(MOD_PKPD, paras, ev1, inits,         #x for name of drug
              omega = omega_rtv, 
              sigma = sigma_rtv, 
              nSub = 1, seed = 12)
```

So how do I write a for-loop that separately inputs all the parameter values for each drug and then stores it into a simulated data frame that is the name of the drug?

I've tried to read some other questions that have been posted here, but I feel like I'm not quite sure how to implement it on my problem. I hope someone can help.